# I only see a fraction of the scene

Tags: 3d-view

I just started to do cubes on blender... And I pressed a key(don't know which one) and I only see a part from all the scene.

[image: Blender screenshot]

I don't know how to make reference to this for searching what did I press...

Can someone explain me what did I do and how to reverse that?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Did you accidentally enable the clipping border?

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to clear it

[image: View Clip]

Comment: Yeah it was that! Thank you sooo much! I was freaking out hahahah

Comment: @YunaSch You can accept the answer, so the question will be closed.

Comment: @Hikariztw Hi. Slight clarification: Having an accepted answer does not 'close' the question. The question remains open, answers can still be added and the accepted answer can still be changed.

Comment: @RayMairlot Oh, I mean... **done**? How do say that word in English?

Comment: @Hikariztw Well, as I said, the status of the question doesn't change at all and any part of it, including the accepted answer, can change, so it isn't really ever 'finished' or 'dealt with'.